# Unable to setup couchbase operator 1.2 with persistent volume on local storage class

Tags: kubernetes, couchbase, persistent-storage, persistent-volumes

I am trying to setup couchbase operator 1.2 on my local system.
i followed the following steps :

- [Install the Couchbase Admission Controller](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/1.2/install-admission-controller.html).
- [Deploy the Couchbase Autonomous Operator](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/1.2/install-kubernetes.html).
- [Deploy the Couchbase Cluster](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/1.2/deploying-couchbase.html).
- [Access CouchBase from UI](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/1.2/accessing-couchbase.html).

But the problem with this is that as soon as the system or docker resets or the pod resets, the cluster's data is lost.

So for the same I tried to do it by adding persistent volume with local storage class as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/1.2/persistent-volumes-setup.html#local-storage-class-experimental) but the result was still the same. The pod still gets resets. and i am unable to find the reason for the same.

So if anyone can advise on how to do the same with persistent volume on local storage class. I have successfully created a storage class. Just having problem while getting the cluster up and keep the consistency for the same.

Here is the yamls that i used to create the storage class and pv and pv claim

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
 name: myssd
provisioner: local
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
 name: couchbase-data-2
 labels:
    type: local
spec:
 capacity:
  storage: 10Gi
 accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
 storageClassName: myssd
 hostPath:
    path: "/home/<user>/cb-storage/"
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-test-claim-2
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: myssd
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local StorageClass definitions do not match. Local storage class should use `provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner`.

Comment: Also you're using `storageClassName: manual`. If so then I am not sure that why would you bother creating a local storage class?

Answer (score 2):

Persistent volume using `hostPath` is not durable. Use a [`local`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) volume. Compared to `hostPath` volumes, `local` volumes can be used in a durable and portable manner without manually scheduling Pods to nodes, as the system is aware of the volume's node constraints by looking at the node affinity on the `PersistentVolume`.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: couchbase-data
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /home/<User>/cb-storage/
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node1
          - node2
          - node3
          - node4
```

You don't need to create a PersistentVolume manually because the storage class will do that internally.

Also you need to configure the `local` volume provisioner as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739026/kubernetes-what-is-the-best-practice-for-create-dynamic-local-volume-to-auto-as/62740063#62740063) so that dynamic provisioning using the local storage class happens.

Comment: i tried it , but the cocuhbase cluster pod got stuck in pending state.

Comment: same as @Abhishektomar. I am using rancher local path provisioner, and the pod hangs in pending state.