# Need to run stateful applications on kubernetes cluster bootstrapped with Kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a kubernetes cluster bootstrapped with kubeadm. I want to run stateful applications on it but dont want to use hostpath. Is there any way to run stateful applications without using cloud storage(like EBS, Azure Disk etc) and hostPath? I saw a few articles about setting up glusterFS server and then use it, but haven't got it running.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [local storage provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner) as discussed in this question  [Kubernetes: What is the best practice for create dynamic local volume to auto assign PVs for PVCs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739026/kubernetes-what-is-the-best-practice-for-create-dynamic-local-volume-to-auto-as/62740063#62740063)

Compared to `hostPath` volumes, local volumes can be used in a durable and portable manner without manually scheduling Pods to nodes, as the system is aware of the volume's node constraints by looking at the node affinity on the `PersistentVolume`

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
 name: myssd
provisioner: local
```

Check this discussion [Unable to setup couchbase operator 1.2 with persistent volume on local storage class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62888429/unable-to-setup-couchbase-operator-1-2-with-persistent-volume-on-local-storage-c)