# pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims ECK (Elasticsearch on Kubernetes)

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy elastic on kubernetes https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/index.html on a local minikube cluster. I have already installed the operator.

When i apply the elasticsearch cluster below, i get the following pod error:

> running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "data-es-es-default-0":
> pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

**volume/claim:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

--

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

**elastic.yml**

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: data-es
spec:
  version: 7.4.2
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 2
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: standard
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
    config:
      node.master: true
      node.data: true
      node.ingest: true
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
      xpack.security.authc.realms:
        native:
          native1: 
            order: 1
---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: data-kibana
spec:
  version: 7.4.2
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: data-es
```

**kubectl get pvc**

[image: NAME STATUS VOLUME CAPACITY ACCESS MODES STORAGECLASS AGE elasticsearch-data Bound elasticsearch-data 10Gi RWO standard 8m45s elasticsearch-data-data-es-es-default-0 Pending standard 7m40s elasticsearch-data-data-es-es-default-1 Pending standard 7m39s]

Answer (score 6):

> pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Above error means there is no `persistentVolume` that can be bound to the `PersistentVolumeClaim`. By default `local-storage` does not really create a `persistentVolume` dynamically.

To use dynamic provisioning mechanism of `local-storage` storage class you need to configure the `local-storage` class so that it can provision the `persistentVolume`. Check this discussion [Kubernetes: What is the best practice for create dynamic local volume to auto assign PVs for PVCs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739026/kubernetes-what-is-the-best-practice-for-create-dynamic-local-volume-to-auto-as/62740063#62740063).

Alternatively without using dynamic provisioning mechanism of a storageclass you need to create a `persistentVolume` using `hostPath` which can be bound to the `PersistentVolumeClaim`.But this is not a recommended solution for production usage. Check this guide [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/).

`PersistentVolumeClaim` will be automatically created based on `volumeClaimTemplates` in the elastic yaml. Hence you should not create a
`PersistentVolumeClaim`.

Since `nodeSets` count is 2 two `PersistentVolumeClaim` is created. So you need to create two `persistentVolume`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data1
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data2
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation on how to do it without dynamic provisioning?

Comment: So ive done this but unfortauntly my elasticsearch still showing up as pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Comment: updated question, still same error even after adding PersistantVolume and claim

Comment: i don';t understand why because elastic is automatically creating those extra 2 pvc

Comment: Yes...it's creating the pvc automatically..now since you created a PV and PVC which got bound to each other..those two PVC is now pending. So remove manually created PVC and create just two PV

Comment: Thanks @ArghyaSadhu it worked as you described, just created PV and apply deployment without any pvc