# How do I know how much memory I should provide in k8s pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have applied a elasticsearch on k8s in my Mac (a minikube cluster). The elasticsearch configure file is:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.10.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          env:
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: -Xms2g -Xmx2g
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 4Gi
              cpu: 4
            limits:
              memory: 4Gi
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: standard
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
```

after I run `kubectl apply -f es.yaml`, the pod and services are created but the pod is pending.

```
$kubectl get services
NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes                ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP    28h
quickstart-es-default     ClusterIP   None             <none>        9200/TCP   21m
quickstart-es-http        ClusterIP   10.103.177.195   <none>        9200/TCP   21m
quickstart-es-transport   ClusterIP   None             <none>        9300/TCP   21m
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
quickstart-es-default-0   0/1     Pending   0          21m
```

the output of `describe pods` is:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  22m (x2 over 22m)   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  40s (x17 over 22m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient memory.
```

It seems that I don't have enough memory in my pod.  How can I allocate more memories to my pod?

Comment: have you created pv and pvc? [pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894472/pod-has-unbound-immediate-persistentvolumeclaims-eck-elasticsearch-on-kubernete)

Comment: I have updated my configuration but still get the two warnings.

Comment: It seems like a lot of these configuration issues are discussed in the [Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/index.html), especially the "Manage compute resources" subpage; have you read through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minikube itself starts with [DefaultMemory = 2048](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/232080ae0cbcf9cb9a388eb76cc11cf6884e19c0/pkg/minikube/constants/constants.go#L102), you are hitting this limit.

Using  minikube you should think in advance how much resources your pods/replicas use in total, so that you can use [--memory flag](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/200/files) to allocated need amount of RAM.

You already got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64995757/9929015) in separate question. In addition to that I would add that you **should always** do `minikube delete` prior to start `minikube` with `--memory=` option, eg `minikube start --memory=8192`

You can always check you current memory configuration by `kubectl describe node` in `Capacity` section, e.g.

```
Capacity:
  cpu:                        1
  ...
  memory:                     3785984Ki
  pods:                       110
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Why does it show memory `3785984Ki` when you specify 8192?

Comment: This is output from diff consoles and clusters, sorry for confusing :)